# JavaFX Scene Builder - Preview stays in fullscreen mode

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, preview

I've encountered what might be a bug, but I do want to ensure there isn't a setting I missed somewhere...

I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder (this has the same behavior in Gluon Scene Builder), on macOS X High Sierra.

The Scene Builder application is operating in fullscreen mode, and when I press cmd+P to launch a preview window for the FXML project loaded, it opens normally, like so:
[image]

But if I put the preview into fullscreen (fills the screen space, not in fullscreen mode like scene builder app) by pressing the green plus at the top left, and then close it (or shrink back to normal size and then close), it reopens back in fullscreen.

My informal solution is to shrink the fullscreen window to normal size, then minimize the window (which also makes the screen black), then reopen the preview and then close it. That makes it open at normal size again.

My question is whether or not this is a bug. Is there a more simple solution or is this even the intended behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: This behaviour may be related to this bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191885

Comment: @mipa If I read correctly, the issue here is similar, but it said that it was no longer resizable after shrinking. The window is resizable for me at that point but when I close the window and open a new preview it starts in fullscreen. I suspect these behaviors are related though.